# Excel 2007 VBA - Using Sheets.Add to create a chart at the end of a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, office-2007

I'm trying to implement a private subroutine to add a Sheet to the active workbook (Sheet being used so that one can choose to add xlForms, xlWorksheet, etc).

But I'm having a bizarre problem with where new charts get created relative to the other sheets in the workbook.

I start off by deleting the sheet of the same name (if it exists) and then use the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count()), _
Type:=sheet_type).Name = sheet_name
```

Where `sheet_type` is an optional parameter of the enum `XlSheetType`, and `sheet_name` is a `string`.

It works completely fine for every available argument such as `xlWorksheet`, `xlDialogSheet`, and even the `xl4MacroSheet` -- but for some reason will create the `xlChart` 1 position before the end, as opposed to the making it the last sheet in the workbook.

So sample I/O (starting off with only 3 sheets):

```
> Create_Sheet "Test", sheet_type:=xlWorksheet
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2 | Sheet 3 | Test

> Create_Sheet "Test", sheet_type:=xlDialogSheet
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2 | Sheet 3 | Test

> Create_Sheet "Test", sheet_type:=xlChart
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2 | Test | Sheet 3
```

`Sheets.count()` properly returns 3 in the previous examples (because I start with only Sheets 1, 2, and 3), and so it should hypothetically position it after the 3rd sheet, but it doesn't.
Attempting to do `Sheets.count() + 1` for testing only gives me an array subscript out of range runtime exception (which is to be expected).

I've even tested just the base code of:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count()), _ 
Type:=xlChart).Name = "Test"
```

and I still wind up getting the same result.

So basically my question is this: am I doing something wrong here? Is there any specific reason as to why a chart can't be added to the end of the Workbook? Or is this perhaps a problem/bug in VB that needs to be fixed?

I'm using Office 2007, so alternatively is it an error that has been fixed in newer versions?

Any input would help.

**EDIT:**
It's worth noting that `After:=Sheets(Sheets.count())` produces the same location as `After:=Sheets(Sheets.count() - 1)`, but only in the case that `Type:=xlChart`

**EDIT 2**
This is even more interesting. If you create one Chart, place it as the last sheet in the workbook, and use the following code:

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add After:=Charts(1)
```

Excel will automatically re-orient the charts so that a Worksheet is last.

For example, if you have:

```
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2 | Sheet 3 | Chart 1
```

and use the code, you will get

```
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2 | Chart 1 | Chart 2 | Sheet 3
```

Comment: This is interesting, i test it with my Excel 2010 and i'm getting the same response. `Before` seems to be working. Also putting it `After` any sheet except the last sheet works. i'll keep testing and see what i'll find

Comment: Well I'm glad it's not just me, but I really hope there's a solution though. Seems bizarre that this issue only happens when it's xlChart.

Comment: See here: http://books.google.com/books?id=wlLQlMuSwAcC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=vba+add+chart+at+end+of+workbook&source=bl&ots=EmmLbQJoju&sig=DavNAdtOdgvpMSbsi21I0zzWQ0w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J5n5UvSGONGiqwGilIGIDw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=vba%20add%20chart%20at%20end%20of%20workbook&f=false. Seems to be a known problem, and there is a suggested solution there.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the link. That's pretty much the solution I'm using now, it just seems crazy that that's the only available option. I guess they probably keep it for legacy purposes now

Comment: @TimWilliams that's good to know. i'm still wondrin' though why it should be that way. i'm still condsidering though that there must be some rule out there which might explain this.

Comment: @L42 - even [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107622) doesn't mention a reason for the behavior.

Comment: I can't be of much help here but I recall when I tortured myself with VBA and Excel that (a) getting the precise order was tricky, and (b) you could get random failures... which we had to wrap try/catch like blocks around to try and add the sheet, then test if if worked before moving to the next one. I feel your pain.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use a chart sheet? Why not just embed the chart in a worksheet?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers I was just trying to make a modular subroutine to add any kind of sheet when I stumbled on this issue. It's not that I have any requirement or need to us it, it was just something that stumped me and I wanted to know if it was a known issue, and if there was a way to overcome it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure if this will help you, but yes, it has the same odd behavior here, and could not find any "clean" way to make the sheet last, so my solution was that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count()), _
Type:=xlChart).Name = sheet_name
Sheets(sheet_name).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count())
```

Comment: This looks like it'd be a good workaround, might be worth accepting as an answer.